# Window 10 Mail freezes when clicking on a mail-item

Tags: windows-10, windows-mail

When I click on a mail-item in the Windows 10 Mail -App, the app freezes and I have to kill it via task-manager. 
I tried to change the account-settings of the mail, but this has not helped.

This behavior is new, until now it worked without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use my windows with another language than my countries language. In the locale settings of windows 10 I have installed two languages.

It turned out, that on the alternate (my countries) langue, the language pack was not installed. Up to now this was not a problem, but it seems after a windows mail update, the language pack was mandatory and therefore windows mail crashes. Probably it's a problem with the spell checker.

**To correct this**: Go to control panel -> Clock, Language, Region -> Language -> Language Options and install for every language the language pack where it is not installed (restart is needed).